# How to achieve multiple elements drag drop in javascript at once

Tags: javascript, dom

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
  <head>
  <style>
  #div1 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  }

  p{
  cursor:pointer;
  }
  </style>
  <script>
  function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }

  function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  }

  function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  }

  function ChangeColor(id){
      document.getElementById(id).style.color = "red";
  }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

  <br>
  <p id="drag1" onclick="ChangeColor('drag1')" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69"><b>one</b></p>

  <p id="drag2" onclick="ChangeColor('drag2')" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69"><b>two</b></p>

  <p id="drag3" onclick="ChangeColor('drag3')" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69"><b>three</b></p>

  <p id="drag4" onclick="ChangeColor('drag4')" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69"><b>four</b></p>

  </body>
  </html>
```

How to **drag** and **drop** multiple elements by selecting at once.

Just like in my code, when i will click on each 



 tags it will change color to red. whoever is selected they are red color.

There are total 4 



 tags

suppose i choosed 3 **ptags** by clicking and the marked **red** after clicking.

I wants to **drag** and **drop** all marked three elements to div **(drop zone).**

same will apply for 2 



 tags selected for.

Is there any way to achieve that ?

Please have a look

Comment: Can you provide some code examples? We can elaborate an answer but with the amount of data we have, it can be not what you're looking for.

Comment: please run this code. you can understand. this much is the code. it will select multiple onclick then can be draggable selected elements